# Authorize non admin account to access OneDrive for Business files

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I want my application to access my users **OneDrive for Business** files (both read and write access). It should work as an alternative browsing client, so the user just has to login and then browse his files.

With personal OneDrive using the v2 Endpoint, it works flawlessly.

When I try to login my OneDrive for Business account I get an error stating that my application requires some privileges that only Admins can grant.

But.. From the app panel ( https://apps.dev.microsoft.com ) my application requires only permission that non-admin users can request (under delegate authorization). The Application authorization list empty.

I also tried to remove ALL the permission required, save, wait some minutes and retry.. and even without any permission required i still get the same error.

I tried making new application, checking all the permission, refreshing the app's key.. but i always get the same error. If i try to login the same account from other commercial application it works.

I also don't have access to any admin account to see a list of authorization required by my app.

I'm really out of ideas, what i can try?

Comment: Could you provide the complete list of scopes you've requested?

Comment: thank you for your answer, how do i check what scope i'm requesting? i just removed every permission from apps.dev.microsoft.com under the "Microsoft Graph authorization" but i cannot find anything about scopes

Comment: Ok thanks for that, the framework i was using to comunicate with OneDrive for Business had some hardcoded scopes that required admin grant. Now its working! :)

Comment: Glad to hear it is working. Which framework were you using?